# Golang inbound channel not receiving inside a goroutine

Tags: go, channel

Please help me understand why the inbound `<-done` channel is not being picked up in this case?

```
func main() {
    done := make(chan bool)
    println("enter")
    defer func() {
        println("exit")
    }()
    defer func() {
        println("  notify start")
        done <- true
        println("  notify end")
    }()     
    go func() {
        println("    wait start")
        <-done
        println("    wait end")
    }()
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond) // << when this is removed, it works.
}
```

I'm expecting the output to be:

```
enter
  notify start
    wait start
    wait end
  notify end
exit
```

But instead it's:

```
enter
    wait start
  notify start
  notify end
exit
```

I initially assumed that the `done` channel was somehow being closed or cleaned up early, but it results in the same unexpected behavior even when the `done` is global.

Shouldn't `<-done` block until `done <- true` occurs? And vice versa?

## Resolution

It seems that I was expecting the program to wait for all of the goroutines to completed before exiting. This is an incorrect assumption.

Here's an dirty workaround:

```
func main() {
    done, reallydone := make(chan bool), make(chan bool)
    println("enter")
    defer func() {
        <-reallydone
        println("exit")
    }()
    go func() {
        println("    wait start")
        <-done
        println("    wait end")
        reallydone <- true
    }()
    defer func() {
        println("  notify start")
        done <- true
        println("  notify end")
    }()
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use sleep, it gives time for the goroutine to start, then by the time it reads from the channel, main exits before the last `println("    wait end")` gets called.

However if you don't call sleep, defer will block until the goroutine reads from it and that gives it enough time to print.

If you move the code to a different function and call it from main it will work as expected.

```
func stuff() {
    done := make(chan bool)
    println("enter")
    defer func() {
        println("exit")
    }()
    go func() {
        println("    wait start")
        <-done
        println("    wait end")
    }()
    defer func() {
        println("  notify start")
        done <- true
        println("  notify end")
    }()
}
func main() {
    stuff()
}
```

Comment: The `Sleep` call is only there as a placeholder for calls that may be blocking or not. Shouldn't `<-done` block until `done <- true` is called?

Comment: It does, but main exits and `os.Stdout` gets closed before "wait end" gets printed, now if you move it to a separate function and call it from main, all that will happen before main exits so everything works as expected.

Comment: I don't think moving it to a separate function helps resolve the Unexpected Output. For example, http://play.golang.org/p/SgyLMjCS-0 results in the same issue. But, you are correct that os.Stdout is being closed early.

Comment: @jojaba that's odd, i've been testing it locally and works as expected, must be something in 1.4.

Comment: No, no number of functions will make a difference here.  The fundamental problem is expecting to results from code that was run asynchronously without the anything being expressed in the program indicating it should wait.  It's the standard `func main() { go fmt.Printf("Hello world!\n") }` that seems to confuse people somehow.

Comment: @Dustin on go in tip, it seems to work, so they might have changed something in the scheduler.

Comment: @OneOfOne Things that aren't safe can appear to work when you're lucky. It's just not correct, though.  If you don't have a join point, you have no way to guarantee observation of something being done asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence of events on the `done` channel: "[when] the channel is unbuffered communication succeeds only when both a sender and receiver are ready." For your example,

The `done` channel is unbuffered: `main`.

```
done := make(chan bool)
```

Receive waiting for a send: `go func()`.

```
<-done
```

Receive ready (`<-done`), send: `defer func()`.

```
done <- true
```

The `main` function ends and does not wait for the goroutine (`go func()`) to finish.

Output:

```
enter
    wait start
  notify start
  notify end
exit
```

> [The Go Programming Language
>   Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Channel types](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Channel_types)
>
> A channel provides a mechanism for concurrently executing functions to
>   communicate by sending and receiving values of a specified element
>   type. The value of an uninitialized channel is nil.
>
> A new, initialized channel value can be made using the built-in
>   function make, which takes the channel type and an optional capacity
>   as arguments:
>
> ```
> make(chan int, 100)
> ```
>
> The capacity, in number of elements, sets the size of the buffer in
>   the channel. If the capacity is zero or absent, the channel is
>   unbuffered and communication succeeds only when both a sender and
>   receiver are ready. Otherwise, the channel is buffered and
>   communication succeeds without blocking if the buffer is not full
>   (sends) or not empty (receives). A nil channel is never ready for
>   communication.
>
> [Go statements](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_execution)
>
> Program execution begins by initializing the main package and then
>   invoking the function main. When that function invocation returns, the
>   program exits. It does not wait for other (non-main) goroutines to
>   complete.

Comment: While this is good general information, it does not answer my question. It simply restates what the code in question already does.

Comment: Thanks, your edited response about the program exiting early addresses the problem.